# Ionic adding android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS permission in app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, android-permissions

I am having `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />` in manifest but I don't need, also as android uses groups of permissions instead of single permission when asking the user to grant them which is in Contacts group. [More info about it](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html). this is all I found out after search.

I want to remove this permission because this is the reason why I see contact permission in the app info screen.

I am having only this in my `config.xml`

```
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="300000" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="WKPort" value="8080" />
```

and in `package.json` has these plugins listed (does any of plugin automatically generate certain permission requirements?)

```
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-globalization": {},
      "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {
        "GMS_VERSION": "11.0.1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To locate you"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": {
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "your usage message"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepicker": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "845225319173258",
        "APP_NAME": "Fixi",
        "FACEBOOK_HYBRID_APP_EVENTS": "false",
        "FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "4.40.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {},
      "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "com.googleusercontent.apps.210603718696-n7l7im3akied7en16i7uueajrdlfen1h"
      }
    }
```

can anyone please help me out with this? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: cordova-plugin-googleplus is adding the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> plugin.

Comment: But it necessary permission for google login?? Because of it I am seeing contact permission in app info screen in android device and I am not using anything related to contact in my app.

Comment: If you are using Google login plugin then the permission will anyhow  showup.

Comment: agree, but it is adding contact permission in app info in settings. I don't use the contact info in my app but it is because of `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission it is adding contact permission silently